# Arch Linux UEFI boot menu clutter

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, uefi

My boot menu looked like this straight after Arch Linux installation:

```
1. reFind boot manager
2. Windows boot manager
3. SanDisk partition 1
4. Kingston partition 1
```

Where the SanDisk is the Linux drive and Kingston is the windows drive.

Every now and then I checked the boot menu entries and they started looking more like this:

```
1. reFind boot manager
2. Windows boot manager
3. SanDisk partition 1
4. SanDisk partition 1
5. SanDisk partition 1
6. Kingston partition 1
```

Now they look like this:

```
1. reFind boot manager
2. Windows boot manager
3. SanDisk partition 1
4. SanDisk partition 1
5. SanDisk partition 1
6. SanDisk partition 1
7. SanDisk partition 1
8. SanDisk partition 1
9. SanDisk partition 1
10. SanDisk partition 1
11. SanDisk partition 1
12. SanDisk partition 1
13. SanDisk partition 1
14. SanDisk partition 1
15. SanDisk partition 1
16. SanDisk partition 1
17. SanDisk partition 1
18. SanDisk partition 1
19. SanDisk partition 1
20. SanDisk partition 1
21. SanDisk partition 1
22. SanDisk partition 1
23. SanDisk partition 1
24. SanDisk partition 1
25. Kingston partition 1
```

What could be causing this 'spam' of boot entries? SanDisk partition 1 is where the /boot is located for Arch linux. I have systemd-boot installed and reFind to manage multiple drives. I tried flashing the UEFI and it hasn't helped. I think 25 entries is the limit since it's not increasing anymore. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first comment is that you probably don't need both rEFInd and systemd-boot. It's conceivable that one or the other (probably not rEFInd, unless the Arch developers have made significant changes to its scripts) is causing the duplicating entries, so unless you have a compelling reason to keep both boot managers installed, removing one of them *might* prevent further entries from appearing. This is a long shot, but as a general rule, it's good to not install more software than you need, since doing so can cause bizarre problems in some cases.

There's also a slim chance that some other boot program is being launched without your knowledge and it's causing this problem. I've seen bug reports about some Red Hat tools, which are designed to correct problems with buggy firmware that forgets boot entries, doing this. I haven't followed that issue very closely, but I think this bug is fixed by now. Also, it normally replicates the Fedora entry, not something more generic like your `SanDisk partition 1` entry, so I doubt if this specific software is to blame; I mention it just as an example of a *possible* cause. Searching your ESP for `.efi` files you don't understand -- and particularly for files that might be launched by your default boot entry but that aren't the intended boot manager -- may be worth doing.

The most likely cause, though, is a firmware bug. You don't say what filesystem or partition type code you've given your `/boot` partition, but if that's your ESP (as is common on Arch installations), your firmware could be looking for a fallback boot loader (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`) and adding an entry for it on every boot. Ordinarily, of course, it shouldn't do this on every boot; but if there's a bug, all bets are off. If there is no fallback boot loader on that filesystem, then that could be what's triggering the bug. Examining the nature of the boot entry with `efibootmgr -v` in Arch Linux might provide some clues.

You can remove excess entries with `efibootmgr`, as in `efibootmgr -b 3 -B` to remove the `Boot0003` entry. Of course, if the firmware is constantly adding the entries back, you'd need to write a startup script to locate and delete the excess entries -- or just live with them cluttering your boot menu. If you can figure out what's triggering the bug, you might be able to reconfigure your system to avoid the trigger -- say, by adding an `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file, if its absence is the trigger.

A better long-term solution, if I'm right, is to upgrade your firmware. (Your motherboard or computer manufacturer probably calls these upgrades "BIOS updates" or something similar.) This might or might not eliminate the problem going forward. It *probably* won't eliminate the existing excess entries, but it might prevent new ones from being created. Be aware that the update *might* also have the negative effect of deleting your valid entries, so you should be prepared with an emergency boot medium in case you need to re-create those entries after updating your firmware.